# Find invalid numbers - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table:

table1

```
column_name    value
Test1          80933Y355220
Test1          8093363X5220
Test1          809336355220
Test1          80.98
Test1          -80.98

Test2          1234
Test2          abc
Test2          12-23-09
```

I need to identify all the invalid number values present in the column `value`

Output should be:

```
column_name    value
Test1          80933Y355220
Test1          8093363X5220

Test2          abc
Test2          12-23-09
```

Is there a way to get this list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common way to solve this is with a user-defined function:

```
create or replace function is_number (p_str in varchar2) return varchar2 is
n number;
rv varchar2(1);
begin
  begin
    n := to_number(p_str);
    rv := 'Y';
  exception
    when others then
      rv := 'N';
  end;
  return rv;
end;
/

select column_name, value, is_number(value) as is_number
from table1
where is_number(value) = 'N'
/
```

In Oracle 12c R2 we acquired a built-in function to do it: `validate_conversion()` which handles lots of data types. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD).

```
select column_name
       , value
from table1
where validate_conversion(value as number) = 0
/
```

Here is the inevitable [demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=81180d9af1e3b4911b0184e54d34eedd).

Regex solutions are tricky to get right. It's easy to formulate expressions which exclude valid numbers (such as `-80.98`) or include non-numbers (such as (`12-34-56`). Even we do get that bit right (as [Gordon's solution does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56408098/146325)) what happens if we want to allow decimal separators or currency symbols?  Or scientific notation? That's a messy regex. It's easy to extend a UDF to handle a format mask and `validate_conversion()` does it natively:

```
SELECT VALIDATE_CONVERSION('$100,00' AS NUMBER,
         '$999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''')
FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `regexp_like()` with this pattern:

```
SELECT column_name, value
FROM table1
WHERE  NOT REGEXP_LIKE(value, '^[-]?[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]*$')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to give an Oracle 12.1 answer, it doesn't have [`validate_conversion`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html) or the `on conversion error` clause of [`to_date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html), but it does support [PL/SQL functions in a WITH clause](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABJFIDC), allowing something like this:

```
with function is_number(str varchar2) return varchar2
     as
         n number;
     begin
         n := str; return 'Y';
     exception
         when others then return 'N';
     end;
select d.column_name
     , d.value
from   demo d
where  is_number(d.value) = 'N'
```